# vagrant not showing gui errors

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, vmware-workstation, vagrantfile

I've enabled vagrant's GUI as following

```
config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
  v.gui  = true

  v.vmx["memsize"] = "3072"
  v.vmx["numvcpus"] = "1"
  v.vmx["displayName"] = "xyz"
  v.vmx["annotation"] = "xyz"
end
```

Still I am getting following error

```
An error occurred while executing `vmrun`, a utility for controlling
VMware machines. The command and output are below:

Command: ["start", "/home/it6/projects/xyz/vagrant/.vagrant/machines/default/vmware_workstation/9ecd4376-4ec4-416e-8919-8d6ea9198097/precise-vmware-basebox-1391995859.vmx", "nogui", {:notify=>[:stdout, :stderr]}]

Stdout: Error: The operation was canceled

Stderr:
```

So it is showing standard error and hence I am not able to debug it. Can anyone show me how to enable gui so i can get more descriptive error hence I can solve this mysterious error.

Comment: According to the Vagrant VMware docs (https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vmware/configuration.html) you are enabling the GUI mode correctly. To isolate the problem, you might want to start from a new simple Vagrantfile, then add back your configuration a piece at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the solution. When I ran the `vagrant up` command after opening the VMWare program it started showing the gui error. So making sure that VMWare was running in background solved my issue.